# How do I apply RandomScore to a FunctionScore query using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to apply RandomScore to a functionScore query as shown below (i've simplified list of filters):

```
sd.Query(q => q
    .FunctionScore(fs => fs
        .Query(fsq => fsq.MatchAll())
        .Functions(
            fx => fx.Weight(0.8).Filter(f => f.Term("ImageSize", "Small")),
            fx => fx.Weight(0.7).Filter(f => f.Exists(t => t.ThumbnailUrl)))
        .RandomScore(74)
        .ScoreMode(FunctionScoreMode.Multiply)
        .BoostMode(FunctionBoostMode.Multiply)
    )
);
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

> ElasticsearchParseException[You can either define "functions":[...] or
>   a single function, not both. Found "functions": [...] already, now
>   encountering "random_score".];

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Many thanks.

Comment: I would have imagined that `RandomScore` is a function, as well. So, I'd try placing it inside `Functions` and define it as a function just like the other two.

Comment: Issue reported [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1559)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Rob above this is a known bug and will be fixed in next release - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1559